# How to calibrate piezoelectric sensor using charge amplifier

Tags: amplifier, calibration

I have a pressure sensor kistler 6051B1, which is 6 pC / bar.
I’m trying to calibrate the sensor in order to use. I have a charge amplifier to read the output, but I honestly have no idea even how to start.
I’m using an oscilloscope from Hantek.

Can someone please point me a direction how to calibrate and read the output voltage?

Thank you
[image: Pressure sensor]

[image: charger amplifier]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your sensor is rated at 6 pC/bar. Your charge amplifier has a front panel setting for gain which in your photograph is set to 1.00 mV/pC. Therefore, if your sensor is exposed to 1 bar, it will output 6 pC which, in turn, will be converted into 6 mV at the charge amplifier output. You can change the gain using the front panel switches. There is also a switch that allows you to choose a gain of X1 or X10. You should consult the manual for the charge amplifier to better understand the use of these switches. Also note the symbol in front of the sensor Sensitivity specification. I believe it means that the sensitivity spec (6 pC/bar) is only approximate and shouldn't be relied on for accurate measurements. If you need good accuracy you will have to provide a calibrated pressure so the sensitivity of your sensor can be more accurately determined.